# Can you solve the gibberish case?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

You are sitting in a restaurant, in your usual place when you notice a man speaking what sounds like. Gibberish? You write it all down and go home. Late at night you wake up and try to make heads or tails of it. Can you do it?

> Interesting. Seahorse apples wiping. Heat if myself; happy electron.
>   Winning artificial sand. drifting if grumpy grandpa Italian net grab.
>   lift in key enterprise. Cap race and zebra yuck.!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@indubitablee [has already found](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/51530/18250) that by

> Taking the first letters You get the phrase *'I saw him; he was digging like crazy!'*

But I don't think this is the final answer. You see

> By taking the 1st of the 1st word, 2nd of the 2nd, etc and repeating at the ';'.

You get:

> **I** s**a**w hi**m**; **h**e w**a**s di**g**ging lik**e** craz**y**!

Which gives

> **I am Hagey**

Which could be a reference to

> <strike>[Gerald Hagey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerald_Hagey)</strike> *OP confirms that his name is just 'Hagey' and that there is a second part coming to explain.*

So I believe that is the final answer.

Comment: Seems like a coincidence. There is no sequential pattern. It breaks halfway and starts again.

Comment: @Techidiot that could just be because it would be hard to continue as you would result in long words

Comment: why would Gerald Hagey be 'digging like crazy'?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry no idea. I just noticed this and posted this to see if it was relevant. OP seems to have disappeared though, so can't get confirmation either way

Comment: @Techidiot wow seems like this was the correct answer

Comment: @JonMarkPerry well there is the confirmation I guess

Comment: Or the OP decided to make this the correct answer on a whim. I like the idea of a second level to the obvious first-level solution, but c'mon: the founder of a university in the Canadian backwaters is a bit bland as answer.

Comment: @MOehm I suppose so, they are after all a new user. Or this isn't their puzzle, and they don't know the answer so just chose this. I agree that the answer is a bit... odd.

Comment: I'd be far more concerned by the fact that Gerald Hagey died in 1988.  Are you the boy from *The Sixth Sense*?

Comment: 6 things:
1. I am Hagey IS the final answer.
2. I did not mean for it to refer to Gerald Hagey. Sorry bout that. 
3. There will be another part of the puzzle coming out soon.
4.This is my puzzle!
5. I did have the Hagey answer in my mind because it's  important later on.
Kindest regards

Comment: @IsaacSoto ah ok. I will remove that then. thanks for confirmation. Glad there is a second part coming, this left me very confused :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to confuse all of you guys. Also Why I "suddenly disappered" was because I went on a vacation and there was no internet. sorry and thank you for understanding.

Comment: "6 things:" ... followed by a list of 5 things.  Oh, that @IsaacSoto, always leaving us wanting more!  Bring on part 2 :)

Comment: @Rubio OMG so sorry. I think I meant to put something but forgot. Yeah i'll fix that.

Comment: 6: The second part does not explain WHY his name is Hagey. But it does explain - if you figure it out - why he said I am hagey. Thank you and there will be another part coming after the second part, which is out now! see it here https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51890/the-case-of-the-strange-coffee/51891#51891.

Answer (score 12):

Is it:

> I saw him; he was digging like crazy!

Because

> The first letter of each word. The periods mark the end of the word.

Comment: Can you fix the capitalization? It's bothering me lol.

Comment: Good Job! But thats not the complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Interesting. Seahorse apples wiping. Heat if myself; happy electron. Winning artificial sand. drifting if grumpy grandpa Italian net grab. lift in key enterprise. Cap race and zebra yuck.!

I tried this way:

> Interesting. She was hopelessly weeping. If it (was) myself; have in election. Winning eighty percent. Drinking champagne in  grand The-Italian night club. Lifting (with) glee into uprise. Comprise in surprise.

Reason:

> Since the person was telling 'gibberish'; so I can assume the pronunciation of the person wasn't clear; that may lead to misinterpretation.
>
>
>
>  1. Interesting was probably same as interesting, in satirical sense.
>
>  2. Seahorse apples wiping `<=` *she was hopelessly weeping*
>
>    (Seahorse `<=` *She was*, apples `<=` *hopelessly*, wiping `<=` *weeping*)
>
>  3. Heat  if myself `<=` If it myself `<=` If it myself `<=`If it (was) myself. (slight re-order done.)
>
>  4. Winning artificial sand `<=` Winning arti---ficialsand `<=` Winning Eighty percent.
>
>  5.  drifting if grumpy grandpa Italian net grab `<=` drinking in champagne  grand the italian night club.
>  
>  (Drifting `<=` drinking, if `<=` in, grumpy `<=` champagne, grandpa `<=` grand---the, italian=italian, net `<=` night, grab `<=` club) Slight reorder gives-
>  Drinking champagne in grand The-Italian night club.
>
>
>  lift in key enterprise `<=` lift-in glee ent-r-pise `<=` lifting glee into uprise `<=` Lifting (with) glee into uprise. 
>
>
>   Cap race and Zebra Yuck `<=` comprise in surprise.
>  (Cap race `<=` comprise, Zebra-yuck `<=` Su(r)pra-yish <= Surprise).

NB.

> I just read the paragraph 4 or 5 times and it came out from itself.

Comment: This my friend...

is not the answer.
Sincerely 
-Isaac.

Comment: I just tried because after reading the paragraph several times, it seemed to giving-out some meaning this way. Thanks :)

Comment: Your welcome, I hope you can solve my next one!(:

Comment: @AlwaysConfused this was already answered, so there probably wasn't a need to post this. However I appreciate you are trying to show your ideas. Just try not to answer a solved question in the future unless you have a good alternative answer (e.g. for a riddle). Thanks Beastly :)