# The case of the strange coffee

Tags: cipher

When you figure out that [the guy speaking Gibberish](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/51529/18250) meant

> I am Hagey

you go back to the restaurant the following day, and hope for the best. When you walk in you notice the man who said the Gibberish in the first place but not the other man. After you order your food and start eating you hear the door bell chime and see the other man walk in and sit down. You hear him say  something but it's not all that clear...

...something to do with, coffee? Anyways after he says that he starts spouting random numbers all over the place and then leaves. As soon as you hear him talking you got your notepad ready and after he finished you got this:

78 79 87 32 84 72 65 84 32 87 69 32 75 78 79 87 32 89 79 85 32 65 82 69 32 
80 82 79 70 69 83 83 79 82 32 72 65 71 69 89 32 87 69 67 65 78 32 71 73 86 69 32 89 79 85 32 84 72 69 32 66 79 88 190

It's up to you to solve it. Can you do it?

Hint:

> What the man said before he said the numbers was: "did you know you can program with coffee"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Decrypting the cipher we get

> using decimal to ASCII: "NOW THAT WE KNOW YOU ARE PROFESSOR HAGEY WE CAN GIVE YOU THE BOX."
>
>  There are a few mistakes in the encoding: there's a space missing between "WE" and "CAN", a space missing between the two "83"s that make up the Ss in PROFESSOR, and the last character (a period) should be encoded as 46. The rest matches up with the intended plaintext.

OP points out in comments that the intended encoding was actually

> [Javascript keycodes](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes). Most of them match up with their ASCII counterparts, but the period is in fact encoded as 190 in this encoding.

Comment: I think it's an error. The word *professor* contains an error as well.. Not sure though.. And, coffee script was used for Drop Box development in case if its relevant.

Comment: That is the correct answer!
And the last character is a period.

Comment: I put the two 83s together on purpose and I will fix the space in between the we and can. But the number for the period is the correct one for the javascript key code numbers that I used. I didn't think using decimal to ACSII would work to. But I guess it did congratulations!

Comment: Ah, I guess I got lucky then with trying a different encoding that worked :)

Comment: Yeah, but that's still pretty neat that it worked instead.