# This one's for you

Tags: cipher

Hello I will send you messages from time to time, they will get trickier and more difficult. I can't tell you my name. You will have to do the cipher. This one is quit easy and won't be that challenging. But when you answer the question I have given you please be honest. Thank you. - Unknown.

0100100100100000011010110110111001101111011101110010000001110100011010000110100101110011001000000111001101100101011001010110110101110011001000000110111101100100011001000010000001100010011101010111010000100000010010010010000001101110011001010110010101100100001000000111100101101111011101010010000001110100011011110010000001100011011000010111001001110010011110010010000001101111011011100010000001101101011110010010000001110011011001010110001101110010011001010111010000100000011010010110111001100110011011110111001001101101011000010111010001101001011011110110111000101110001000000100110101111001001000000110111001100001011011010110010100100000011010010111001100100000010010100110000101100011011010110010000001000011011010000110000101110010011011000110010101110011011101000110111101101110001011100010000001000001011011100110010000100000010010010010000001100011011011110110110101100101001000000110011001110010011011110110110100100000011000010010000001101100011010010110111001100101001000000110111101100110001000000110100101101110011001100110000101101101011011110111010101110011001000000110001001110101011100100110011101101100011000010111001001110011001011100010000001000011011000010110111000100000011110010110111101110101001000000110101101100101011001010111000000100000011011010111100100100000011100110110010101100011011100100110010101110100001000000111001101100001011001100110010100100000011011110111001000100000011101110110100101101100011011000010000001111001011011110111010100100000011000100110010101110100011100100110000101111001001000000110110101100101001111110010000001001001001000000110111001100101011001010110010000100000011101000110111100100000011010110110111001101111011101110010000001110100011010000110000101101110011010110010000001111001011011110111010100101110

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The binary is very easily decoded into an ASCII message:

> I know this seems odd but I need you to carry on my secret information. My name is Jack Charleston. And I come from a line of infamous burglars. Can you keep my secret safe or will you betray me? I need to know thank you.

Whether the message itself has any hidden meaning...

> There is a minor league baseball player named [Jack Charleston](http://www.milb.com/player/index.jsp?player_id=665067). There's no information about him being a descendant of infamous burglars.

I don't know if there is anything else here. Maybe it makes sense in the context of [the author's other puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51890/the-case-of-the-strange-coffee), which seem to be part of an ongoing series.

To answer the "question": Sure, I'll keep it safe. Bring on the next puzzle!

Comment: Very good! I hope you enjoyed it and I know it was easy I just wanted to start the series in a mysterious way. Trust me they will get harder!

Comment: There is no reference to Jack Charleston. Also these are not part of the other ongoing series. Thank you!